# Javascript classList.add to element with 0px height

Tags: javascript

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm trying to add a class to an element that has `0px` height to begin with.

```js
const teamMemberBioShow = function() {
  const bio = document.querySelector(".bio");
  if (bio.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    bio.classList.remove("hidden");
    bio.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    bio.classList.remove("show");
    bio.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

const teamMemberBioMore = document.querySelector(".bio-more");

teamMemberBioMore.addEventListener('click', teamMemberBioShow);
```

```css
.bio.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.bio.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio hidden">
  Bio goes here
</div>

<div class="bio-more">Read Bio</div>
```

On click, the class `.show` is added and the `.hidden` class is removed. But it doesn't work if the `.hidden` class has `0px` assigned to it.

Comment: You set the height to 0, but the _text content_ of the element still overflows it. And in combination with `opacity: 0`, it appears to _overlay_ your second div, so that your click event never reaches that one. Add `overflow: hidden` to make the first div _hide_ its overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you put height 0 but do not set the `overflow: hidden` the text content of that div will overflow and cover the clickable text, so the click event won't be dispatched:

```js
const teamMemberBioShow = function() {
  const bio = document.querySelector(".bio");
  if (bio.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    bio.classList.remove("hidden");
    bio.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    bio.classList.remove("show");
    bio.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

const teamMemberBioMore = document.querySelector(".bio-more");

teamMemberBioMore.addEventListener('click', teamMemberBioShow);
```

```css
.bio.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bio.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio hidden">
  Bio goes here
</div>

<div class="bio-more">Read Bio</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because even if your element .bio.hidden has an opacity of 0, it messes up with the click event, and it overflows over the other div.

Try putting `display: none` if you want to hide an element